# Quotient of the direct product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, direct-product

It occurs to me the following is true:
$$(\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m) / \mathbb{Z}_k \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n/k} \times \mathbb{Z}_m$$
when $k \mid n$.
But I fail to see the way to prove that.

The way I want to use it is to show
$$(\mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{20}) / \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{20}$$
My idea is to start by decomposing the direct product as following:
$$(\mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{20}) / \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong (\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{20}) / \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{20}$$
However, I am still unsure whether the last step is always true, and I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: I think you mean $(\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m) / (\mathbb{Z}_k  \times 0)$

Comment: It matters *which exact copy of* $\mathbb Z_k$ you take inside $\mathbb Z_n\times\mathbb Z_m$.

Comment: Following the previous two comment with something concrete for you to look at: find all subgroups of order $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and find all the quotients.

Comment: I think I get it know, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarizing the comments; it is not true in general. The simplest example is the quotient
$$(\Bbb{Z}_4\times\Bbb{Z}_2)/\Bbb{Z}_2.$$
Then the isomorphism type of the quotient depends on whether you take the quotient w.r.t. the subgroup $\Bbb{Z}_2\subset\Bbb{Z}_4$ of the first factor, or the subgroup $\Bbb{Z}_2\subset\Bbb{Z}_2$ of the second factor. And there is even a third subgroup $\Bbb{Z}_2\subset\Bbb{Z}_4\times\Bbb{Z}_2$, that is not contained in either factor.